Modifying Managed Package Custom Metadata Type Record
I Created a Managed Package on a Developer org, the package contains multiple components such as custom objects, apex classes, and custom metadata types.
the Custom metadata type records are public, and the Field Visibility for the fields that i want to modify it in the subscriber org is Subscriber editable, I installed the package in a sandbox and when i try to modify the Subscriber editable fields in the sandbox using metadata api from APEX code in the same managed package, I can't do it, I can modify the fields values only using the Custom metadata api setup page.
does anyone know a way to be able to modify the custom metadata type record fields?
this is the methods I am using.
public void savePreferences() {
    try {
        // Prepare the updated metadata
        MetadataService.MetadataPort oMetadataPort = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
        MetadataService.CustomMetadata oCustomMetadata = new MetadataService.CustomMetadata();
        oCustomMetadata.fullName = 'MyNamespace__Salesforce_Org_Setting__mdt.Defaults';
        oCustomMetadata.Label = 'Defaults';   
        // Populate new values
        oCustomMetadata.values = new List<MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue>{
            createCustomMetadataValue('MyNamespace__Enable_Debug_Logs__c', String.valueOf(EnableDebugLogs)),
            createCustomMetadataValue('MyNamespace__Synchronous_Threshold1__c', String.valueOf(SyncThreshold1)),
            createCustomMetadataValue('MyNamespace__Synchronous_Threshold2__c', String.valueOf(SyncThreshold2)),
            createCustomMetadataValue('MyNamespace__Batch_Size__c', String.valueOf(BatchSize))
        };  
        // Deploy changes
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> Results = oMetadataPort.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { oCustomMetadata });
        utilities.WriteDebug('Results: ' + Results);
        if (Results != null && !Results.isEmpty() && Results[0].success) {
            addSuccessMessage(System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Preferences_saved_successfully_Message_Label);
            showToast('success', System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Preferences_saved_successfully_Message_Label);
        }
        else {
            addErrorMessage(System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Preferences_saved_Failed_Message_Label + (Results != null && !Results.isEmpty() ? Results[0].errors[0].message : 'Unknown error'));
            showToast('error', System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Preferences_saved_Failed_Message_Label + (Results != null && !Results.isEmpty() ? Results[0].errors[0].message : 'Unknown error'));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        addErrorMessage('Error saving preferences: ' + e.getMessage());
        showToast('error', 'Error saving preferences: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}





public void saveDefaultValues() {
    try {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort oMetadataPort = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
        List<MetadataService.Metadata> CustomMetadataList = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();     
        for (DefaultValue oDefaultValue : ConfessorDefaultValues) {
            MetadataService.CustomMetadata oCustomMetadata = new MetadataService.CustomMetadata();
            oCustomMetadata.fullName = 'MyNamespace__Salesforce_Org_Default_Value__mdt.' + oDefaultValue.field.replace(' ', '_');
            oCustomMetadata.Label = oDefaultValue.field;
            oCustomMetadata.values = new List<MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue>{
                createCustomMetadataValue('MyNamespace__Field_Default_Value__c', oDefaultValue.value)
            };      
            CustomMetadataList.add(oCustomMetadata);
        }
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> Results = oMetadataPort.updateMetadata(CustomMetadataList);    
        Boolean AllSuccess = true;
        for (MetadataService.SaveResult SaveResult : Results) {
            if (!SaveResult.success) {
                AllSuccess = false;
                addErrorMessage(System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Default_Values_saved_Failed_Message_Label + SaveResult.errors[0].message);
                showToast('error', System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Default_Values_saved_Failed_Message_Label + SaveResult.errors[0].message);
            }
        }
        if (AllSuccess) {
            addSuccessMessage(System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Default_Values_saved_successfully_Message_Label);
            showToast('success', System.Label.Org_Admin_VFP_Default_Values_saved_successfully_Message_Label);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        addErrorMessage('Error saving default values: ' + e.getMessage());
        showToast('error', 'Error saving default values: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}


Being sure that the Custom Metadata fields are subscriber editable, you can update a record via Metadata.Operations class. Its enqueueDeployment(container, callback) method takes a container, an object that contains the set of metadata components to deploy, and an instance of class implementing Metadata.DeployCallback (the callback) as input.
The cointainer is just an instance of Metadata.DeployContainer and its addMetadata() needs an instance of the Metadata.CustomMetadata(Metadata.Metadata is an abstract class, therefore you need the concrete one), a wrapper that holds every info about the CMT record to be updated/created, so you need to build that specific instance.
Since that class represent a generic Custom Metadata Type, it cannot have a property for each real field, indeed it has a values property that is a list of Metadata.CustomMetadataValue. For each field to update you need to create an entry of Metadata.CustomMetadataValue.
You could retrieve the record you need to update via getInstance(), then overwrite the values of the fields you need to change and pass that instance to the method that will update it, which will leverage getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() build up the list of Metadata.CustomMetadataValue.
These advices result in the following code:
public class SalesforceOrgSettingsHandler implements Metadata.DeployCallback {
    public static Id updateRecord(Salesforce_Org_Setting__mdt cmtRecord) {
        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadataRecord =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadataRecord.fullName = cmtRecord.NamespacePrefix + '__Salesforce_Org_Setting__mdt.' + cmtRecord.QualifiedApiName;
        customMetadataRecord.label = cmtRecord.Label;
        customMetadataRecord.values = new List<Metadata.CustomMetadataValue>();

        Map<String, Object> fields = cmtRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        for (String fieldName : fields.keySet()) {
            if (fieldName.startsWith(cmtRecord.NamespacePrefix)) {
                Metadata.CustomMetadataValue cmtProperty = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
                cmtProperty.field = fieldName;
                cmtProperty.value = cmtRecord.get(fieldName);
                customMetadataRecord.values.add(cmtProperty);
            }
        }

        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadataRecord);
        Id jobId;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { // Needed since you cannot enqueue a deployment in test context
            jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, new SalesforceOrgSettingsHandler());
        }
        return jobId;
    }
    
    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        // Handle the result
        System.debug('Metadata Deployed : ' + (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded));
    }
}

Then your savePreferences method could be:
public void savePreferences() {
    Salesforce_Org_Setting__mdt cmtRecord = Salesforce_Org_Setting__mdt.getInstance('Defaults'); // No need of the namespace prefix since the code is in the same managed package
    cmtRecord = cmtRecord.clone(false, false, false, false);
    cmtRecord.Enable_Debug_Logs__c = String.valueOf(EnableDebugLogs);
    cmtRecord.Synchronous_Threshold1__c = String.valueOf(SyncThreshold1);
    cmtRecord.Synchronous_Threshold2__c = String.valueOf(SyncThreshold1);
    cmtRecord.Batch_Size__c = String.valueOf(BatchSize);
    Id jobId = SalesforceOrgSettingsHandler.updateRecord(cmtRecord);
    
    
    // everything else you need
}

Please note that Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment enqueue a deploy operation against your org, you'll see it from Setup > Deployment Status, therefore it is not a synchronous action, nor an immediate one.
In the subscriber org, the user must be grant Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions and Customize Application permissions system permissions (which cannot be added to a permission set included into the managed package).
Moreover, if the managed package is not approved by Salesforce, the subscriber org must enable Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Version via Apex from Setup > Apex Settings

I tried exactly what you suggested and now i got " Record is read-only" error and cannot modify the CMT record even in the developer org

@AbdulrahmanBahri which line throws that error?

cmtRecord.Enable_Debug_Logs__c = String.valueOf(EnableDebugLogs);

@AbdulrahmanBahri My bad, I missed a line. Right after getting the custom metadata record you have to clone it. I updated the answer

ok adding the cloning logic fixed the issue, i am able to modify it in the developer org, but after installing the package in the subscriber org, i get this error "Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex"

@AbdulrahmanBahri in the subscriber org does the user have Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions and Customize Application permissions?

the user in the subscriber org is a system administrator

@AbdulrahmanBahri From Setup > Apex Settings, is Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Version via Apex checked?

it worked ! thanks a lot Ruben
